# Overheat timing for Qonqr

Tags: qonqr

I'm playing the location MMO strategy game [Qonqr](http://www.qonqr.com/) and I'm wondering if anyone has done the math on whether it is more beneficial to let the overheat timer expire before launching bots or to continuously launch bots as soon as the required number are available.  There is a table for regen rates [here](http://qonqr.wikia.com/wiki/Regeneration_Info), my question is specifically would you be able to deploy more bots by continuously deploying once the required bots are available (for this argument lets say 500 bots are the required amount), or should you time it such that you stay in one of the other regen zones.